# Auto click + key press for Mac software?

Tags: macos, automation

I need to run some automation inside of software I have installed on my Mac. I was wondering what I should use? Thank you.

Comment: Check out Keyboard Maestro. It can simulate clicks: https://www.keyboardmaestro.com/main/

Comment: Thank you! This works.